# git post-receive hook: shebang throws error (#!/bin/bash: not found)

Tags: git, bash, jenkins, githooks, git-post-receive

we are using a git server side hook for notifying jenkins builds on the post-receive event.

The script itself is working as intended, it gets successfully executed.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Notifying Jenkins"
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    if [ "$newrev" != "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" ] #do not notify    jenkins for deleted branches, print message instead
    then
        branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
        echo "== $branch =="
        curl -s "http://[JENKINS_DOMAIN]/git/notifyCommit?url=[PUSH_URL]"
    else
        echo "DELETED REMOTE BRANCH >$refname<, REMOVE JENKINS JOB IF EXISTING"
    fi
done
```

The only problem we have is that we get an error message from the script execution for the shebang line `#!/bin/bash` with the following content:

`remote: hooks/post-receive: 1: hooks/post-receive: #!/bin/bash: not found`

We checked the following things:

- bash is installed and working on git server
- bash is executable/readable for all
- changing shebang to `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/dash` throws same error (with corresponding shell)
- removing shebang throws error for the second line (doesn't find echo) but all other echo commands will be executed successfully
- removing shebang and adding an empty first line results in
  `remote: hooks/post-receive: 1: hooks/post-receive: : not found`

Does anyone has another idea why we get this error? It isn't very problematic but it would be nice to know why this happens and what to do to fix this.

System information:

- Linux Debian 7
- access control is done with apache server

  - www-data user has permission for accessing, reading and executing the post-receive hook

Best regards

Comment: ... and obviously the file has the execute bit set, or git would not try to run it.  What system is this on, and do you have extra access controls set up on it?  (E.g., Linux with ACLs)  Meanwhile, this is very suspicious: if the line says `#!/bin/bash` why does the error say `#!/bin/sh`?

Comment: ah, a little typo, copied the error message from the wrong shell shebang used. Fixed this in post. Additional information will be added when i have it...

Comment: Run "which bash", use the output as the path to put as #!<output_path_here>

Comment: @Arun: which bash returns `/bin/bash` as default but for apache the shell is defined as `/bin/dash`. All these options were tested and didn't solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shebang might interact with the BOM of an UTF-8 file. Save the file as UTF-8 without BOM.

[Wikipedia - Shebang#Magic_number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29#Magic_number)

> The shebang characters are represented by the same two bytes in
>   extended ASCII encodings, including UTF-8, which is commonly used for
>   scripts and other text files on current Unix-like systems. However,
>   UTF-8 files may begin with the optional byte order mark (BOM); if the
>   "exec" function specifically detects the bytes 0x23 0x21, then the
>   presence of the BOM (0xEF 0xBB 0xBF) before the shebang will prevent
>   the script interpreter from being executed.

Comment: That is the solution: remove BOM from file and everything works as intended. For linux: `tail --bytes=+4 <SCRIPTFILE> > <SCRIPTFILE>.new` does the trick.